# Making a button shift down when replacing text above

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jquery fading effects, however the button beneath disappears then re-appears, while I want this button to go down to its new position (by go down I mean move without disappearing). Note: the texts have different lengths therefor the button moves to a new position on the screen.

```js
var text1 = toggleContent.find('.toggle-content-text').find('p');
var text2 = "foo bar"
text1.fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
  text1.html(text2);
  $(this).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-content">
    <div class="toggle-content-text">
      <p> Find the prospects </p>
      <a href="/"> View Platform </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried fade in/out for the button which doesn't work.

Comment: What is `toggleContent` supposed to be?

Comment: it's a parent div of "toggle-content-text" .

Comment: Ok, then you should add this part of JavaScript too as it seems to be relevant.